# Iterating "For" loop with 2 brackets

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop

I am reading Programming Ruby (4th Edition) and I don't quite understand how we can iterate a `for` loop with 2 brackets.

```
require_relative "words_from_string.rb"
require_relative "count_frequency.rb"

raw_text = %{hey hey hey man man bro}

word_list = words_from_string(raw_text)
counts = count_frequency(word_list)
sorted = counts.sort_by {|word, count| count }
top_five = sorted.last(5)

for i in 0...5
    word = top_five[i][0]   #don't understand why there are 2 brackets. 
    count = top_five[i][1]  #how does the iterator work with 2 brackets.
    puts "#{word}: #{count}"
end
```

words_from_string.rb

```
def words_from_string(string)
    string.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
end
```

count_frequency.rb

```
def count_frequency(word_list)
    counts = Hash.new(0)

    for word in word_list
        counts[word] += 1
    end

    counts
end
```

Comment: There is two brackets (i.e. two indices) because the array is nested, something like `[["hey", 3], ["man", 2], ["bro", 1]]`. `top_five[1]` is thus `["man", 2]`; `top_five[1][0]` is `"man"`.

Comment: Try simply printing out `top_five`. You have an array of arrays. Then it should make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `sort_by` for hash, it convert hash to two-dimensional array.

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
=> {}
counts[1] = 2
=> 2
counts[2] = 1
=> 1
counts
=> {1=>2, 2=>1}
sorted = counts.sort_by{ |k, v| v }
=> [[2, 1], [1, 2]]
sorted[0][1]
=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `top_five` array is made up of elements which are themselves arrays with two elements - the first is the word and the second is the number of times it appeared in `raw_text`.

The loop iterates over these pairs and extracts the word (the first element of each array, index 0) to `word` and the count (the second element in each array, index 1) to `count`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because 'topfive' is a multi-dimensional array (a two-dimension in your case), meaning, it is an array, containing an array.

If you're going to play around with it:
If you puts topfive[n], it will give you an array that has a structure of [string, int], which is the [word,count] in your example.

The code uses two brackets in order for you to access the elements inside the array.
In the example, topfive[i][0] will get the word, and topfive[i][1] will get the count or the number of words

Answer (score 1):

I played around with my console and based on your answers, i finally got it!

So essentially, first [ ] is the index of the main array and the second [ ] is the index for the nested array. Now i get it! Brilliant! Thanks guys!

```
   def words_from_string(string)
       string.downcase.scan(/[\w']+/)
   end

          def count_frequency(word_list)
              counts = Hash.new(0)
              for word in word_list
              counts[word] += 1
              end
            counts
          end

raw_text = %{hey hey hey man man bro yo yo yo yo yo ye ye ya oi ui}

    word_list = words_from_string(raw_text)
    counts = count_frequency(word_list)
    sorted = counts.sort_by {|word, count| count}
    top_five = sorted.last(5)

    print word_list
    #produces
    ["hey", "hey", "hey", "man", "man", "bro", "yo", "yo", "yo", "yo", "yo", "ye", "ye", "ya", "oi", "ui"]

    print counts
    #produces
    {"hey"=>3, "man"=>2, "bro"=>1, "yo"=>5, "ye"=>2, "ya"=>1, "oi"=>1, "ui"=>1}

    print sorted
    #produces
    [["ui", 1], ["ya", 1], ["oi", 1], ["bro", 1], ["man", 2], ["ye", 2], ["hey", 3], ["yo", 5]]

    print top_five
    #produces
    [["bro", 1], ["man", 2], ["ye", 2], ["hey", 3], ["yo", 5]]

    for i in 0...5
    word = top_five[i][0]   
    count = top_five[i][1]  
    puts "#{word}: #{count}"
  end
    #produces
    bro: 1
    man: 2
    ye: 2
    hey: 3
    yo: 5


        puts top_five[4][1] 
        #produces 
        "5"       
        puts top_five[4][0] 
        #produces 
        "yo"
```